# How to unify adjacent quads in a quad mesh?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I'm looking for an algorithm that given a quad mesh with many a regular grid of small quads, would produce a similar looking quad mesh, but with as many of the small quads unified into larger quads, as much as possible.

For example, given a quad mesh that looks like this:

[image: input mesh]

The output would be something like this:

[image: output mesh]

I realise that producing a optimal solution is probably an NP-Hard problem, so the output would obviously need to be less than optimal.

What is this problem called? Are there established algorithms for it?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the problem is NP-hard if you seek the minimum:
"[Tiling an orthogonal polygon with squares](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16661/1884)."

See [this link](http://www.benzedrine.ch/polygon-partition.html) for heuristic solutions:

---

[image: PartSq]

---

Key search phrase: partitioning an orthogonal polygon into squares.